# Android google map apiv2 authorization failure

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have generate keystore using two type of command as follow

> - keytool -genkey -v -keystore mykestorename.jks -alias aliasname &    keytool -selfcert -alias aliasname -keystore mykestorename.jks
> - keytool -genkey -v -keystore mykestorename.keystore -alias aliasname    -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000000

and I generate sha1 key using following command

> - keytool -list -V -alias alias name -keystore "keystore path"

I create API key in Google console the generated key passes **Authorization failure** error
and showing grey color plain background in map fragment

Comment: I had the same trouble yesterday, my mistake was that I activated the wrong API in the Google console, which was the Google Maps API V2 (which also lets you create an Android key) instead of the Google Maps Android API V2. Perhaps you made the same mistake.

Comment: @Ascorbin no i select Google Map Android API V2 only, what is way to create private kestore using keytool?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. But also check if you entered the right package name in the Google console.

Comment: @Ascorbin i give all fields correctly and i create 10+ keystore with different package and sha1 key but i found same error...could tel me the way you create keystore using keytool...